# I installed Hadood 3.2.1 in Ubuntu 20.04 but I am getting an error

Tags: hadoop

I am a newbie at Linux and Hadoop.  I installed Hadoop-3.2.1 in Ubuntu 20.04 I followed the steps on site https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-apache-hadoop-hbase-on-ubuntu/

I got this error when I ran this command:

```
~$ hadoop version
Error: Could not find or load main class ”-Djava.library.path=.usr.local.hadoop..lib.native”
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ”-Djava/library/path=/usr/local/hadoop//lib/native”
```

Comment: Why are there dots here? `.usr.local.hadoop` Or slashes here? `java/library/path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may be missing one of the environment variables needed for Hadoop. It’s not able to find one of the jar files for Hadoop native library. For more precise installation please follow below article,

https://hadooptutorials.info/2020/10/05/part-1-apache-hadoop-installation-on-single-node-cluster-with-google-cloud-virtual-machine/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer I was able to make it work setting up the Environment variables as you suggested.